# Problems starting up sonar service with MSSQL

Tags: sonarqube

We have installed Sonar 3.6.2 on a Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise x64 machine, and started it successfully as a windows service, using the embedded H2 database.  Our issues have started when attempting to switch the database across to a Microsoft SQL Server 2008 instance.

We are using the supplied jtds database driver (v1.2.7), with the following settings uncommented in the sonar.properties file:

```
#----- Microsoft SQLServer 
sonar.jdbc.username:         <user>
sonar.jdbc.password:         *********** 
sonar.jdbc.url:              jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://<host>:<port>/sonar;domain=<domain>;useNTLMv2=true 
sonar.jdbc.driverClassName:  net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver 

#----- Connection pool settings 
sonar.jdbc.maxActive:                      20 
sonar.jdbc.maxIdle:                        5 
sonar.jdbc.minIdle:                        2 
sonar.jdbc.maxWait:                        5000 
sonar.jdbc.minEvictableIdleTimeMillis:     600000 
sonar.jdbc.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis:  30000 

# Delay (in seconds) between processing of notification queue 
sonar.notifications.delay=60
```

When initially starting sonar, we can see it is creating all the necessary tables.  However, when it gets up to the stage of initializing Hibernate, we see the following error:

```
2013.09.03 14:24:58 INFO  o.s.j.s.AbstractDatabaseConnector  Initializing Hibernate 
2013.09.03 14:25:00 ERROR o.s.s.p.Platform  Missing column: id in sonar.GLOBALTEST\AUSonardsa.active_rule_changes 
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing column: id in sonar.GLOBALTEST\AUSonardsa.active_rule_changes
```

Connecting to the same database via DBVisualizer with the same AUSonardsa user, I can see that the table 'active_rule_changes' is there, and I can do a simple sql statement 'select id from active_rule_changes' which returns an empty table with the single id column.

Google searches for similar issues (ie, missing columns in tables during the Hibernate initialization) all point to the need to have the 'sonar.jdbc.schema' value set.  However, when we set this value (to 'dbo', for example) the error changes slightly:

```
2013-09-03 16:14:33.436:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/,file:/D:/devtools/Sonar/install/sonar-3.6.2/war/sonar-server/},file:/D:/devtools/Sonar/install/sonar-3.6.2/war/sonar-server 
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing table: active_rule_changes
```

Even when we have our dba move the tables to the dbo schema manually, sonar is still not able to see the active_rule_changes table, regardless of whether or not we have the sonar.jdbc.schema property set.

We have even tried dropping the whole sonar database, recreating a fresh one, and setting the schema property to 'dbo' and starting up sonar again.  In this case it goes ahead and recreates all the tables, gets to the Hibernate Initialization and again complains about not finding the active_rule_changes table.  In this case, even though the schema property was set to 'dbo', the tables still seem to be created under the AUSonardsa user's schema.

Can someone please help us work out what is causing these issues?

Answer (score 0):

Comment out this property, it should work

```
#sonar.jdbc.schema:                         sonar
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the sonar user's default schema to dbo in the database.

Run a query like the below in the database:

```
USE yourDatabase;
ALTER USER yourUser WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = dbo;
```

Then drop all the tables in the database and restart the Sonar service on the server. This should recreate all the tables to be `dbo.<table name>`.

I realized your problem occurred quite a long time ago. We recently came across the same issue and solved it this way. Hopefully this will help other people resolve this issue in the future.